# ITEM name must be unique

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Using Intuit Anywhere QuickBooks Desktop, I am creating items that added without errors to the cloud. Using an ItemQuery, Looking up the item works fine. Here is my XML request and response:

http://pastebin.com/4YaJbgZg

When I run the Intuit Sync Manager, my newly added items enter error state. These items do not exist in QuickBooks, before I run the sync manager. After entering error state, this query will make them appear:

```
        ItemQuery iq = new ItemQuery();
        iq.ErroredObjectsOnly = true;
        var bItems = iq.ExecuteQuery<Item>(dataServices.ServiceContext);
```

How can I find out why these items enter error state? I created a log file using the Intuit Sync Manager, however, I see no error messages about these items. Here is my log:

http://pastebin.com/QhpKHvWF

Comment: Is the ITEM name unique?

Comment: Yes, the name is 12345.

Comment: When you do your query, look for errors in an error state - ErroredObjectsOnly="true". It is possilbe an item exists that is in error.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post and I see items enter error state. I do not know why because they enter the cloud just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QBD Item Create is in beta and is not supported in v2.

[QBD Supported Objects and Operations](http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0500_Supported_Objects)

Support for Item Create will not be added until V3 is released.  For more information about V3, please see the [V3 webinar recording](http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2013/02/quickbooks-api-v3-webinar-recording.html).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. When will this be supported officially?